# Opening WebView links in Safari

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in Cocoa, and I would like to know if there is a way/how to make any link clicked in my webview to launch in Safari (or the default browser). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23):

I just ran into this problem myself, and solved it this way:

My main controller object was set as the policyDelegate for the WebView.

Then implement this method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
    decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
    request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
    decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    NSString *host = [[request URL] host];
    if (host) {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[request URL]];
    } else {
        [listener use];
    }
}
```

I needed to have the check for the host there, because otherwise when I load the initial content of the WebView (just a static html page in my project), it was being launched in Safari.  Now, just links with actual hosts (external links) get sent to Safari, which is the behavior I wanted.  I think I could also have not set the policyDelegate until after the initial page was loaded.

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same problem and the solution I have found is not too intuitive.

As a previous answer indicated, you have to use the `WebPolicyDelegate` protocol, defined in `<WebKit/WebPolicyDelegate.h>`. It is an informal protocol, so you cannot write `@interface MyDelegate : NSObject <WebPolicyDelegate>`.

`#import <WebKit/WebPolicyDelegate.h>` (or the whole WebKit.h) and implement the `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` method as follows:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
  if ([actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionElementKey]) {
    [listener ignore];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[request URL]];
  }
  else {
    [listener use];
  }
}
```

Then set your class as PolicyDelegate for the WebView.

Logic dictates you should use a different key from the `actionInformation` dictionary, namely `WebActionNavigationTypeKey`, whose value *should* be an enum that can include `WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked`. Unfortunately, the values I have seen look random and far beyond the correct range (6 decimal digits integers while the enum goes from 0 to 5).

But, there is something else to check, the `WebActionElementKey`, that returns the HTML entity that originates the navigation action. When loading data in the frame from code, its value is `nil` whereas when user clicks a link, its value is the (parsed) `<a>` entity. Checking it for non-`nil` value does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the tip!
I had to route only the external links to Safari. To get a name anchor (with #) to display in the webView I did following:

```
 - (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
    NSDictionary *info = actionInformation;
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey];
    NSString *path = [url absoluteString];
    NSRange range;

    range = [path rangeOfString:@"file://"];

    if (range.location != 0) {
        // open in Safari ö
        [listener ignore];
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[request URL]];
    }
    else {
        // open in webView because link starts with file://...
        [listener use];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift

Swift example below:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import WebKit


class WebViewManager: WebView {

    private var _urlHome = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        //Sets current object as the receiver of policy delegate
        self.policyDelegate = self
        //Load homepage
        self.loadHomePage()
    }

    func loadHomePage() {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self._urlHome!);
        self.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
    }


    override func webView(webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNewWindowAction actionInformation: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, request: NSURLRequest!, newFrameName frameName: String!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {
        println(__LINE__)
    }

    override func webView(webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, request: NSURLRequest!, frame: WebFrame!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {
        println(request.URL.host)
        if request.URL.host == self._urlHome?.host {
            listener.use()
        }else {
            NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(request.URL)
        }
    }

}
```

--

Do not forget to set Custom Class on Inspector too, choose WebViewManager, otherwise it wouldn't work.

[image: Custom Class]

If you want clicks opened on external browser, use this

```
override func webView(webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, request: NSURLRequest!, frame: WebFrame!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {
    //Check action action type, if click, open an external view
    let info:NSDictionary = actionInformation as NSDictionary
    let mode:Int = info.valueForKey(WebActionNavigationTypeKey) as Int
    if mode == 0 {
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(request.URL)
        self.mainFrame.reload()
    }else{
        listener.use()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the policy callback doesn't get called for clicked links, only while loading a page.