# Webkit WebView not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm using a Webkit WebView in my app but it actually doesn't work. I mean the page loads but when I click a link on the page nothing happens.

This is my webpage: http://www.beginninghtml.altervista.org

And this is my code:

in my `AppDelegate.h`:

`@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webView;`

in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.beginninghtml.altervista.org"];
     NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:req];
}
```

It correctly loads the page but when I click on the links on the page just nothing happens.
Anyone who can help me?

Comment: I actually found the solution to my problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530590/opening-webview-links-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used the following code to open in the Cocoa Webview a link that requires to open a new window:

Set the policyDelegate for you WebView and then implement this code in it:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
    [listener ignore];
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
    [[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:req];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed some of your links request to open new windows rather than opening the page in the current window as usual. It's up to you to [Handle New Window Requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/MultipleWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002026-117573). The section I linked to specifically mentions "nothing happens" if such a link is clicked without handling the request as the web view's UI delegate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try and let you know, anyway it's quite strange you know? I do the same thing in iOs programming with a UIWebView and everything is ok.

Comment: UIWebView is not the same thing as WebView. Besides a common render engine and basic API approach, you just have to dig in and read the docs for the given task on the given platform.

Comment: Well I tried to do what stated in the link you gave me but actually still nothing happens. Probably I made something wrong, these are the steps I followed, can you please tell me if these is the right way?

1. I added a new WebView class called `myWebView`.
2. I set it as the UIDelegate of my WebView.
3. In the implementation of my new class `myWebView` I added the codes in steps 3 and 4 of your link.

Comment: Are you certain the web view that's acting as the delegate is the web view you're controlling? There's too little information to tell what's happening.

Comment: Can you please create a project and do what your link says? I don't think it will take you more than 10 minutes actually. Thank you.

Comment: Did *you* create a new project and do what the documentation said?

Comment: I actually implemented the code to my existing project. But if you think it's better I can create a new project.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong and creating a test project to isolate your problem in a clean, minimalist environment is never a waste of time.

Comment: ok man! I'll try and let you know as soon as I get back home. Anyway, can you please tell me one thing? Which kind of class should i use as uidelegate of my webview? Is it ok using the class AppDelegate (the one created by default in the every new project)?

Comment: I created a new project but still "nothing happens". I actually added an NSLog command to the event used in the link you gave me: actually the NSLog works, the event occurs but the link won't open. If you give me you email I can send you the project. Thank you so much.

Comment: The architecture is your choice. For testing purposes, any controller will do as the delegate, including the app delegate. To help the community rather than just you, let's keep the Q&A on StackOverflow. Post a link to a zipped copy of your bare-bones test project. You can put it on a personal web site or use a file sharing service.

Comment: Ok man, thank you for your support, I can't understand why it doesn't work, I did everything as stated in Apple's Developer guide. Anyway, Here you are the link to my project: http://bitshare.com/files/a582dfhz/WebUIDelegate.zip.html

Comment: You appear to have copied and pasted the code without looking at what it's doing. You're not using a document-based application project but you're asking the app's document controller (which is unused in this app project template) to create a new document ... which it doesn't have. In your case you want to either use a document-based template or implement a window/controller yourself that you can create at runtime. How to do that? Research first then post a separate question if you get stuck.

Comment: yes man I read it but I thought that it was actually referred only to the first two step. Anyway I'll them post a new question. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I actually found the solution to my problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530590/opening-webview-links-in-safari